# Strange behaviours getting all post from wordpress category

Tags: php, wordpress

today i need to get all the posts from a specific category on wordpress.

The code it's pretty basic, and it's like that:

```
print_r(get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'category' => 3)));
```

The id of the category it's obviously 3.
But i receive always the last 5 posts of that category, not all the post present there (something like 60posts).

Anyone know why could happen this strange stuff?

Comment: try `get_posts('numberposts=-1&category=3&post_type=post')`

Comment: Already tried also that one. But return always the last 5 posts. It's pretty unbelievable. I really can't guess what happen there. It's look like that the variable numberposts is not taken at all !?!

Comment: are you passing the post_type ?

Comment: yes, the code it's exaclty:

 print_r(get_posts('numberposts=-1&category=3&post_type=post&fields=ids'));

Comment: are all posts "published"? try passing 'post_status' =>'any'

Comment: changed with this:

print_r(get_posts('numberposts=-1&category=3&post_type=post&fields=ids&post_status=any'));

the problem remains the same...

Comment: This do the trick:
'
$args=array('showposts' => 100,
              'paged' => $paged,
              'category' => 3,
              'fields' => 'ids');
  print_r(query_posts($args));'


No IDEA on why this works and why the get_posts not works... :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php


$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'category' => 3 );

 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
 foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach;  wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```

If this works for you, all you need to do then is to change the output display(the ul and li)

Comment: same result. Only 5 post printed. The additional strange stuff there it's that the list is empty. So This code print 5 element of a list, without url and without title!?!

Comment: very bizzare, where are you putting this?/tyring to print it out to?

Comment: solved, with the use of query_posts instead get_posts() Don't know why get_posts not worked. First time ever, that i had that problem.